# UITableView and UIView in the MasterViewController, UIView invisible

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, master-detail

I'm going to use UITableView in the top of the MasterView and the UIView in the bottom of the MasterView. Here is my temp application: http://www.file-upload.net/download-4547664/MDA_protocol-8.zip.html . Unfortunately the UIView isn't visible and the UITableView takes all place in the MasterView. Maybe some settings are wrong?

Comment: Are you using storyboard? Can you provide a screenshot of the "Document Outline" so that I provide a solution. Meanwhile make sure that in document outline, the UIView is below UITableView.

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using the storyboard and the UIView is below of the UITableView. Please have a look at my template application. (file-upload link) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your MasterView is of type UITableViewController, its only meant to hold a UITableView. I would suggest making your MasterView just a UIViewController and adding a TableView object to the top and a UIView to the bottom.